# How to sort a list with given range in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

If I have a list of size n and I know that the numbers in the list will be between 1 and 2n how would I go about solving it where the worst case would be O(n)?

I was thinking that if it was between 1 and n I could just take the number and swap it with the value of the array at that number - 1 but then it wouldn't sort if there were any duplicate.

I was thinking of a similar approach for the list having number between 1 and 2n but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help please?

Comment: How big can n be? As long as n is not much bigger than the length of the list, counting sort is by far the fastest solution.

Comment: not a very java question tho...

Comment: @SpiderPig n will be the size of the list where n can be of any size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would usually need a non-comparison sort to sort in O(n) time, but this is if you are already given certain information. There are three "main" non-comparison sort algorithms to choose from: counting sort, radix sort, and bucket sort.

Use counting sort if you know that the input are small integers. By Wikipedia, "counting sort is only suitable to use in situations where the variation in keys is not significantly greater than the number of items." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

You can use radix sort if all the numbers you are sorting have the same number of integers. Ex: 211, 311, 122.

Bucket sort may seem like the best option for you. Your approach sounds good, but you do not need an array from 1 to 2n with an index for each number. In bucket sort, you can have an array from 1 to 20, and have something like a linked list within each element. So if you were placing the number 109 it could correspond to the index 10.

Answer (score 7):

**[Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)** can operate in **O(n)** in your case. Have a look on wikipedia's definition

> counting sort is an algorithm for sorting a collection of objects
>   according to keys that are small integers; that is, it is an integer
>   sorting algorithm. It operates by counting the number of objects that
>   have each distinct key value, and using arithmetic on those counts to
>   determine the positions of each key value in the output sequence. Its
>   running time is linear in the number of items and the difference
>   between the maximum and minimum key values, so it is only suitable for
>   direct use in situations where the variation in keys is not
>   significantly greater than the number of items

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use radix sort here. When you have restriction on the input, like in your case, it works well. Check out the algorithm here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: Counting is better than radix for such a well defined problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use radix sort, counting sort, there are lots of O(n) sorts.

But the question is making it really easy for you ...

In Java:

```
int [n] input = {your list of n numbers}; int [2*n] listinorder; int [n] output;

for (int i=0, i<2n, i++) listinorder[i] = -1; // set all values of listinorder to -1

for (int i=0, i < n, i++) listinorder[input[i]] = input[i]; // set the ith value of listinorder to i

int j=0;

for (int i=0, i<2n, i++) if (listinorder(i)  != -1) {output[j] = i; j++};
```

In English:

1. Establish an array (say listinorder) of length 2n.
2. Set every value to -1. Step through the input list.
3. For each value i in the input list, set the corresponding value of
   listinorder to i (ie `listinorder[i]=i`). Then step through the
   values of listinorder which aren't -1 to produce the sorted list.

All O(n).

Comment: "listinorder[i]=i" - you're assuming any given number only appears once in the input.